# To get all questions about "Ruby" that is unanswered

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, unanswered-questions

The URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby

can get all questions about Ruby, but is there a way to easily get all unanswered questions about Ruby.  Probably the Stack Exchange API can be used for that, but is there also a simple URL that produce that result as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit the Unanswered tab and click a Ruby tag (presumably you have one in your interesting tags).  You'll wind up at https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ruby

Comment: what if... for two tags, such as for CSS and HTML?