# To get all questions about “Ruby” that has 0 answers

Tags: support, status-completed, search, unanswered-questions

Related to [To get all questions about "Ruby" that is unanswered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67931/to-get-all-questions-about-ruby-that-is-unanswered)

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ruby

that is, for questions that have no up-voted answers, is there a way to get questions with 0 answers too?

Also, is it possible to get it for two tags, such as for CSS and HTML?  (update: meaning any CSS or HTML questions with 0 answers)

Comment: Awwwwww kittens.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there a page that displays questions with zero answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/is-there-a-page-that-displays-questions-with-zero-answers), which has just earned [status-completed]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type in the following to the search bar:

> [ruby] answers:0

For multiple tags:

> [css] [html] answers:0

Check out the [search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for more information.

Comment: Also available in link form: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[ruby]+answers%3A0

Comment: I think very close... the `[css] [html]` is "and", I think.  Is there a way to say "or"?

Comment: @JianLin Tags with "or" logic are possible through URL manipulation ( just add `+or+` between two tags instead of `+` ) However, as pointed out [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54842/searching-for-text-and-tag-does-not-work/54843#54843), it won't work in combination with `answers:0`.

Comment: @Grace - thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Questions with 0 answers have the "0 answers" highlighted in red. (You aren't color-blind, are you?)

Otherwise, have you tried looking at the advanced search options?

Comment: but then the page will be full of all those questions... the purpose is to filter out and show only the questions with 0 answers

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ruby?tab=noanswers

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/css+html?tab=noanswers

see:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-horror-of-no-answer-revival-and-necromancer/